# Operating System Not Found from bootable USB?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, usb

Hi I am trying to create a bootable USB for Windows 7 (I have superdrive removed).
I went the rEFIt +  Microsoft Bootable USB Tool route and keep getting 
"Operating System Not Found".

I also checked the USB in Disk Utils and it shows as MBR.

USB also shows up if I press "Alt" when booting, but same "Operating system..." error.

How can I fix this?

Spent half a day already...

Comment: From the fact that you say "I have superdrive removed" I'm guessing you're using a Mac, but that isn't clear from your post. Are you?

Comment: Yes I am, Macbook Pro..

Comment: Do you know if your USB of Windows 7 (install DVD?) works? Have you successfully used it on another computer? Or is the question about your bootable USB?

Comment: I used it before, in my superdrive days...

Comment: Used the DVD to boot via the superdrive or this USB with Windows 7?

Comment: used to boot via superdrive - burnt that onto a DVD and installed Win

Comment: How did you create the USB you want to boot from?

Comment: Microsoft USB DVD Download Tool..

Comment: Is this the tool you used: [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)? Please verify the link points to the correct site.

Comment: yes this one exactly.. it actually looks like it's not possible at all to install win7 from USB onto a macbook pro.. unless I do the virtual to physical thing..

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I've tried rEFIt with a USB drive created with Microsoft's tool, and I also tried using Bootcamp's tool to burn the ISO file by editing the info.plist file so that I had the option. In both cases it fails to boot from the USB stick. Also fails if I try it with a Freecom USB DVD drive with the original Windows 7 DVD in the drive which just results in a flashing _ on a black screen. Considering buying an external superdrive to see if I that works.